# Whitespaces in AWS CloudFront for Signed URL's

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm implementing Signed URL's with AWS CloudFront for my files in AWS S3, and my signed URL's are working fine for almost all of my files. The only ones that are not working are those files using whitespaces, e.g. "Hello world.txt"

As per documentation: [Creating a Signed URL Using a Custom Policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-creating-signed-url-custom-policy.html)

> Concatenate the following values in the specified order, and remove the whitespace (including tabs and newline characters) between the parts.

I have a lot of files already stored in AWS S3 and many of them are using whitespaces. Is there any way that I can use Signed URL's for those files?

The signed URL generated is already using %20%. Even i tried to change %20% by + and didn't work.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok... It's working now.

The resource in the policy shouldn't include whitespaces. Therefore, previous to encode the policy, all whitespaces in the Resource should be replaced by '+'. E.g. "Hello+world.txt"

Hope this helps someone.